# Word for final act of kindness before dying

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, idiom-requests, popular-refrains

Is there a word or saying for a final act of kindness, a final change of heart when you know you're about to die? Say, a fatally wounded soldier giving water to an enemy in the same situation. There are many examples from literature and movies - and surely real life - but I can't think of a good word for this.

Comment: I think the closest you'll get is a metaphoric [***parting gift***](http://www.yourdictionary.com/parting-gift) (bestowed by someone leaving this earthly life).

Comment: For single word requests, I think you're supposed to write a sentence and leave a blank in it for the word you're requesting. One reason is that so we know exactly what you're asking. For example, an act of kindness and a change of heart are different things

Comment: You might consider such an act [*a mercy.*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mercy)

Comment: For a last-minute change of heart, a single word is *repentance*. It could also be called a *deathbed conversion*, even without a bed, and even without a religious conversion.

Comment: last honors, last rights, granting pardon, equanimity in death, dying sympathy, dying words of sympathy, extreme unction, viaticum(eucharist given to a dying person) ... Is there even a word for a dying person at all in English? in french you can say "un mourant" = "a dying".

Comment: Isn't any act of altruism,  a sign of  compassion? You could call the last concession or donation  a [good deed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deed)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a perfect match, but it might work for you:

***swan song***

[Wordsmyth.net](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=swan%20song) gives it as "final action or appearance of someone or something."

[Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_song) gives it as "final gesture, effort, or performance given just before death or retirement."

Comment: The downside is that it is often used to refer to an artistic performance.  But I don't think it *has* to be limited to that.

Answer (score 2):

I think a word you could use would be act of **conciliation** or **conciliatory** action or behavior.

Comment: Not specific to a person near death.